# FedUp, unable to upgrade to Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, upgrade, kernel-modules

I am upgrading my Fedora OS to the latest version 20 as the current one is nearing end of life. Fedora introduces a new upgrade method called [FedUp](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp) that allows user to perform an upgrade over the network. I followed the instructions in there and everything went smoothly with no errors in the fedup log:

```
# fedup --network 20
setting up repos...
getting boot images...
.treeinfo.signed                                              | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
setting up update...
finding updates 100% [==========================================================]
verify local files 100% [=======================================================]
testing upgrade transaction
rpm transaction 100% [==========================================================]
rpm install 100% [==============================================================]
setting up system for upgrade
Finished. Reboot to start upgrade.
Packages without updates:
  btparser-0.25-1.fc18.x86_64
  firstboot-18.6-2.fc18.x86_64
  google-chrome-stable-31.0.1650.63-1.x86_64
  kernel-3.11.10-100.fc18.x86_64
  kernel-3.11.7-100.fc18.x86_64
  kernel-modules-extra-3.11.10-100.fc18.x86_64
  kernel-modules-extra-3.11.7-100.fc18.x86_64
  libgssglue-0.4-1.fc18.x86_64
  mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2-1.fc18.x86_64
  mysql-workbench-5.2.47-2.fc18.x86_64
```

Upon reboot, I encountered three errors:

> Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
>   Failed to start IPv6 firewall with ip6tables.
>   Failed to start IPv4 firewall with iptables.

After logging in and upon further examination with lsmod, I notice that several modules are missing, preventing the network from working. The missing modules include:

```
ebtable_nat
ebtables
ip6table_filter
ip6_tables 
microcode
nf_conntrack
nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_conntrack_ipv6
rt2800lib
rt2800usb
snd
uinput
xt_conntrack
xt_limit
```

It appears there are many missing modules, preventing me from completing the upgrade to the latest OS version.

Next I tried upgrading to version 19 by running the command `fedup --network 19`, but it seems to do an upgrade to the same version 20 instead. I also tried upgrading using the non-recommended way from DVD iso file and it generates warnings, advising me not to do so.

I am really fedup. What should I do now?

Comment: "it seems to do an upgrade to the same version 20 instead." The downloaded files are stored in `/var/tmp/system-upgrade` and it won't download the F19 ones unless you delete the existing files.

Comment: The name "FedUp" does seem quite ironic ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest fedup available for your distro.  Check updates-testing for updates.

```
yum --enablerepo=updates-testing upgrade fedup
```

Don't try to jump over releases.  Use standard distro kernel.  Re-enable SELinux if you disabled it.  Don't ignore fedup warnings.

I just upgraded two Fedora 19 systems to Fedora 20.  One of them was upgraded from Fedora 18 in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did only `sudo yum update fedup fedora-release` as per instruction for network installation. As for the rest of your suggestions, I did tried upgrading from 18 to 19 but failed. The kernel is standard. SELinux is not disabled. There are no fedup warnings during the upgrade. I am not sure if having custom partition for `/home` and `/var` is a problem. I can't tell now since I have given up and performed a fresh installation long before your answer came. Anyway, I would accept yours as there is no way I can test it again.