# Fedup fails to update Fedora 19 to 20

Tags: fedora, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my Fedora install from 19 (3.12.8-200.fc19.x86_64) to 20. I have installed and ran `fedup`, it creates a new entry on the boot list but a progress screen is briefly displayed and then it reboots back to Fedora 19.

Here's what I tried:

```
# yum install fedup
# yum --enablerepo=updates-testing upgrade fedup
# fedup --network 20
# fedup-cli --network 20
```

and by following [this post](http://linsec.ca/blog/2013/02/03/im-fedup-with-fedora/):

```
# yum install rpmconf; rpmconf -a 
# find /etc /var -name '*?.rpm?*' 
# yum install yum-utils; package-cleanup --leaves
# package-cleanup --orphans 
# yum install fedup
# fedup-cli --network 20 --debuglog /root/fedupdebug.log
```

Is there a way to log what happens at the post-reboot stage? It seems to be failing at this phase.

Comment: I can't post my log files on pastebin, they're 800kb and 9MB (ouch!)

Comment: I have read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107089/fedup-unable-to-upgrade-to-fedora-20?rq=1 but it didn't help.